# Draw on the Window Titlebar - add Buttons and Progressbar

Tags: wpf

I would like to add a Button next to the Close/Minimize/Maximize-Buttons on the Window titlebar using WPF. Is that possible? 
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this out there is sample here maybe helpful

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/wpf/thread/a248244c-3361-4316-bb70-745b2000431d

Comment: Could you provide better information?  This link is to a page with more links, some of which are dead.